# Why does the length of the array given to np.random.shuffle() affect np.random.uniform()?

Tags: python, numpy, random

Simple example, changing the *values* inside the `aa` array does not change the result of `np.random.uniform()`:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(12345)
aa = np.array([3., 56., 7])
np.random.shuffle(aa)
print(np.random.uniform())
```

But changing its *length* does

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(12345)
aa = np.array([3., 56., 7, 0.])
np.random.shuffle(aa)
print(np.random.uniform())
```

I tried checking the [source](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/2eedaa4cf94cf54bbd4d8428aa39271410f22e9f/numpy/random/mtrand.pyx#L4378), but the way it's written is way above my Python skills.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python uses a pseudo-random number generator, which produces a deterministic sequence of values.  Re-seeding will yield the exact same sequence, but if you use different amounts, you'll end up at different places in the sequence.

Shuffling `n` items calls the random number generator `n-1` times to determine which other element to swap into each position of the array.  Larger `n` means more calls to the PRNG.  Since your shorter array has 1 less item, the PRNG sequences are out of sync by 1 at the end of the two shuffles.  You can confirm this by generating two random numbers rather than one for that scenario:

```
import numpy as np

MAX = 2**32
np.random.seed(12345)
aa = np.array([3., 56., 7, 0.])
np.random.shuffle(aa)
print('randint after shuffling 4 items')
print(np.random.randint(MAX))  # 561383553

print('\ntwo calls to randint after shuffling 3 items')
np.random.seed(12345)
bb = np.array([3., 56., 7])
np.random.shuffle(bb)
print(np.random.randint(MAX))  # 1358822685
print(np.random.randint(MAX))  # 561383553
```